# Python requests.get delivers the wrong web page

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to build a simple scraper to get a lot of book cover images from goodreads.com. My code access every page of the fantasy book list, and gets the book cover of each book on the list. The problem is, it doesn't seem to get beyond page 1. The url for page 2 is just https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/fantasy?page=2 but the get request returns page 1, even when I enter it manually. Here's the code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import os.path

root = "https://www.goodreads.com"
pageno = 2

while pageno < 4:
    page = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/fantasy?page=" + str(pageno))
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    bookno = 4
    imageno = 1
    while bookno < 104:
        for i in range(0, 5):
            try:
                link = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div['+str(bookno)+']/div[1]/a[2]/@href')
                bookpage = requests.get(root+link[0])
                booktree = html.fromstring(bookpage.content)
                coverart = booktree.xpath('//*[@id="coverImage"]/@src')
                file = open("C:/Users/PCP/Desktop/images/book"+str(imageno)+".jpg", "wb")
                file.write(requests.get(coverart[0]).content)
                file.close()
            except:
                continue
            else:
                break
        bookno += 2
        imageno += 1
    pageno += 1
```

Comment: It looks like this is because you have to be signed in to view anything except the first page so it will only return the first page. Annoyingly they are retiring their API so it looks like you will have to make some process to sign-in to your account via requests (look at using requests.session to keep signed in), you could copy the cookies from your browser after signing in there but that would likely be a very short-term solution.

Comment: The URL is not correct, if you manually got to these websites and check the content of page=1 and page=2 they are identical. Thats why you are getting the same response with every page count.

Comment: The URL is correct, the content is only the same when you are not logged in. Login and the two pages show as expected.

Comment: @Frostyfeet909 thanks, thats helpful. But now I'm trying to log in with my email and password using requests.Session , and I'm unsuccessful. I used cookies.get_dict() to check if I logged in, and it returns an empty dictionary.